# GitHub repository for UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute?

Tags: github, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'd like to find the source code for the Asp.Net Core MVC `ApplicationBuilder` extension called `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`.  Based on this documentation http://dotnet.today/en/aspnet5-api/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Builder/StatusCodePagesExtensions/index.html it looks like it's in a class called `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.StatusCodePagesExtensions`.  That page also has a "view it on GitHub" link which would solve my problem but unfortunately it returns a 404.

I have hunted on GitHub to locate this source code but haven't yet been successful.  It does not appear to be in the https://github.com/aspnet/Home repository.  Here's what my search for `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in the aspnet org yields on github:

[image]

What repository contains the source code for the   `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.StatusCodePagesExtensions` class?  Where is that file and how do you find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs#L164

Link may die eventually, so for the future go to: https://github.com/aspnet

And put the method in the top search bar for the org as a whole. In this case there was only 10 uses and I just had to find the one with the method declaration.

EDIT:

What my search screen looked like: 
[image]

Comment: I went to https://github.com/aspnet and searched for `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in the top search bar for the org and got no results and I also tried searching for `StatusCodePagesExtensions` there but also got no results.  How were you able to find this source code?

Comment: @RonC I added a screenshot of the search query and where I saw the usage with an arrow.  Note, It was in the `Code` section on the left.

Comment: Thanks!  But I'm getting different search results, see my updated question for my screenshot.  How can it be that we do the same search on github and get different results?  I must be doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: @RonC Click on `Code` in the left menu.

Comment: A thousand times THANK YOU!